# How to stop getting Incredibuild getting re-installed on VS service pack updates

Tags: visual-studio-2017, incredibuild

Have a very annoying problem,  xoreax Incredibuild keeps getting reinstalled when I apply Visual Studio 2017 updates.

I remove it from Add/Remove and it's fine for a week or too, and then Microsoft release yet another visual studio 2017 update, and lo-and-behold, Incredibuild is back and needs manual removal again.

I really don't want this garbage, Visual Studio is slow enough as it is, without even more useless junk being pushed onto me.

Comment: getting the same on vs2019...